# Some questions about Android Service lifecycle

Tags: java, android, service

From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed

When a Service is indeed killed by the system, is `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` get called?

Consider a code snippet below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        count++;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    ...
}
```

By returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()`, I assume MyService is going to recreate itself after being killed by the system due to low memory scenario. Will the value of count resetted to 0 everytime MyService recreates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When a Service is indeed killed by the system, is onStop() or onDestroy() get called?

There is no `onStop()` available to `Service`. A `Service` may or may not be called with `onDestroy()`.

> Will the value of count resetted to 0 everytime MyService recreates?

Yes.

Comment: my bad, `onStop()` indeed do not exist on Service. What do you mean by `onDestroy()` may or may not be called? Is there some kind of way to make it certain that `onDestroy()` will always be called on this low memory scenario?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian: No. First, if the need for system RAM is very high-priority (e.g., an incoming phone call), Android will not take the time to execute `onDestroy()`, as that may take too long. Second, low memory is not the only reason why your process is terminated. If the user presses Force Stop on your app's screen in Settings, for example, your process is terminated outright, without `onDestroy()` being called on running components. `onDestroy()` is for lightweight cleanup, but do not rely upon it.